# More than one file was found with OS independent path 'lib/armeabi/libBugly.so'

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I tried to debug my application, but an error appeared:

> More than one file was found with OS independent path 'lib/armeabi/libBugly.so'

This is a part of my gradle:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 3
        versionName "1.0"

        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a"
        }
    }

}

dependencies {

    implementation 'com.tencent.bugly:crashreport_upgrade:latest.release'
    implementation 'com.tencent.bugly:nativecrashreport:latest.release'
 }
```

Android Studio 3.1.3, Gradle4.1 in my project.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add something in app's **build.gradle** :

```
android {
  packagingOptions {
    pickFirst 'lib/armeabi/libBugly.so'
  }
}
```

Then, it works.